# d3.js - Position of the graph

Tags: javascript, php, css, d3.js

I want to present my d3 graph with a beamer. But when I use the beamer my graph drops to the right side of my website. But it is just my d3 graph. The other content is still at the same position.

Do you have a hint for me? It is important. Thank you.

Here is my code for the position. I know I should use % or px for the margin. But when I tried this, the graph doesnt appear.

```
<div style="width: 1000px; margin-left: 23%;">
                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
                <script>


var margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 127, left: 430},
    width = 1400 - margin.left - margin.right, 
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
```

My whole code:

```
<style>
.bar {
    fill: steelblue;
}

.bar:hover {
    fill: brown;
}

.axis text {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path, .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.x.axis path {
    display: none;
}
</style>
<body marginwidth="0" marginheight = "0">
<div style="width: 1000px; margin-left: 23%;">
                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
                <script>


var margin = {top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 127, left: 430},
    width = 1400 - margin.left - margin.right, 
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([(height), 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yScale)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(10);


var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
            .attr("class", "chart");

var chart = svg.append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.json("getdata.php", function(error, data) {
  xScale.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.text; }));
  yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d){ return d.count; })]);




  chart.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(data)
        .enter()

        .append("rect")
        .attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return xScale(d.text); })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.count); })
        .attr("height", function(d) { return height - yScale(d.count); })
        .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())

  chart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")  
            .style("text-anchor", "end")
            .attr("dx", "-.8em")
            .attr("dy", ".15em")
            .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)" );


  chart.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y",6 )
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Value");

});

function type(d) {
  d.count = +d.text;
  return d;
}

</script>
            </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I think you're missing some code here.

Comment: I though its enough to figure out my problem. But I can post my whole code here as well if needed ?!?! Thank You!

Comment: In general it's a good idea to post a simple but complete example so that people could do things like take it, paste it into a jsFiddle and see what is happening, for example.  This explains it pretty well: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Okay thank you. I added the code :)

Comment: What is the div that contains you code for? You have it set like this: <div style="width: 1000px; margin-left: 23%;"> but you are appending the chart to the body?

Answer (score 1):

Okay guys. 
I know whats wrong.
I append the chart to the body.

```
var svg = d3.select("body")
```

I just changed it to my div and now its working.

Thank you guys.